# How to translate a video in android 2.2 or 3.0

Tags: android

Hii.. i am new to android.. i am developing an application in which i need to move a video file. I am trying to do this using translate animation but its not really happening. while doing this its the video view which is moving, but actuall video remains at its original place. while moving an image using imageview its happening. I tried doing this in both android 2.2 and 3.0 but the same thing is happening. Can anyone plz help me out with this by sharing some code or giving some suggestion.. Thanx in advance..